Python ctype: argument 2: <class 'Typeerror': wrong type
I use Ren'Py engine and want to implemet Steam leaderboards in to my game.
Steamapi has a method SteamUserStats: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamUserStats#FindOrCreateLeaderboard
Ren'Py uses ctypes-based binding to the Steamworks API: https://github.com/renpy/renpy-build/blob/master/steamapi/steamapi.py
In order to deal with leader board I have to create it in Steamworks interface and then use FindLeaderboard function -> I tried it and this function cannot find created leader board, named "topscores".
I also can use FindOrCreateLeaderboard function to create a leaderboard, but in this case I have an error: "argument 2:  <class 'Type error': wrong type"
I have connection to Steam, as other functions, like checking achievements, work.
Please advise what I can do.
Thanks.
the code I use:
# find my leaderboard
def find_board():
    leaderboard_name = achievement.steamapi.SteamUserStats().FindOrCreateLeaderboard("topscores", 2, 1)
    return leaderboard_name

I expected it to work.

The code is written to take explicit classes for the enumerations.  From steamapi.py, FindOrCreateLeaderboard is a method that calls ISteamUserStatus_FindOrCreateLeaderboard:
def FindOrCreateLeaderboard(self, pchLeaderboardName, eLeaderboardSortMethod, eLeaderboardDisplayType):
    return ISteamUserStats_FindOrCreateLeaderboard(byref(self), pchLeaderboardName, eLeaderboardSortMethod, eLeaderboardDisplayType) # type: ignore

But! ISteamUserStats_FindOrCreateLeaderboard is a C function called by ctypes with these types:
ISteamUserStats_FindOrCreateLeaderboard.argtypes = [ POINTER(ISteamUserStats), c_char_p, ELeaderboardSortMethod, ELeaderboardDisplayType ]

The second parameter is type c_char_p and corresponds to pchLeaderboardName.  A c_char_p needs a bytes object but "topscores" is type str.  Use b'topscores' instead.
The code is also written to take explicit classes for the enumerations, so you may need to use the named enumerations instead.  Try:
from steamapi import k_ELeaderboardSortMethodDescending, k_ELeaderboardDisplayTypeNumeric

# find my leaderboard
def find_board():
    leaderboard_name = achievement.steamapi.SteamUserStats().FindOrCreateLeaderboard(
        b'topscores',
        k_ELeaderboardSortMethodDescending,
        k_ELeaderboardDisplayTypeNumeric)
    return leaderboard_name


I imported like this
from steamapi import ELeaderboardSortMethod, ELeaderboardDisplayType
##Got: ##
type object 'ELeaderboardSortMethod' has no attribute 'k_ELeaderboardSortMethodDescending'
sorry for terrible formatting

@Kamti Updated. I misread the steamapi.py file.

I tried and have an error:
NameError: name 'k_ELeaderboardSortMethodDescending' is not defined
my current code:
from steamapi import ELeaderboardSortMethod, ELeaderboardDisplayType
# find my leaderboard
`def find_board():
leaderboard_name = achievement.steamapi.SteamUserStats().FindOrCreateLeaderboard(
        "topscores", k_ELeaderboardSortMethodDescending, k_ELeaderboardDisplayTypeNumeric)
    return leaderboard_name`


@Kamti They need to be imported from steamapi.

when I import from steamapi import ELeaderboardSortMethod, ELeaderboardDisplayType, k_ELeaderboardSortMethodDescending, k_ELeaderboardDisplayTypeNumeric I get the initial error "argument 2: <class 'Type error': wrong type". I am about to drop it, I read lots of topics a nd tried everything, but it doesn't work. Thanks for your attempt to help, Mark.

@Kamti Updated again.  I think the problem is "topscores" needs to be a bytes string not a Unicode str.  Again, I don't have a reproducible example from your question.  I full error traceback would also help.  I still think you'll need to use the k_ constants as well.

It works, awesome! I managed to create a Leaderboard with your code.
I see the new leaderboard created in Steamworks profile.
I tried to upvote your answer, but have not enough reputation...
There are few other functions, which I struggle with, like: GetLeaderboardName and UploadLeaderboardScore. There is a high chance I will post another questions a bit later...
